# Javers audit framework throwing intermittant SQL exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, audit, sqlexception, javers

We are using javers 5.10.3. During Process Javers complaining about different exceptions in different process and these issues are intermittant. Please assist here

Most frequently occurring this issue and dont know what has wrong here as its intermittent issue.
Error:
org.javers.common.exception.JaversException: SQL_EXCEPTION: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (paymentgalaxy_firstbank.jv_snapshot, CONSTRAINT jv_snapshot_global_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (global_id_fk) REFERENCES jv_global_id (global_id_pk))

NumberFormatException - We are not sure from where its looking this value. We checked out entity and nowhere i found this value.
Error:
at org.javers.core.json.typeadapter.commit.GlobalIdTypeAdapter.deserializeInstanceId(GlobalIdTypeAdapter.java:80) ~[javers-core-5.10.3.jar!/:na]
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TreeTypeAdapter$GsonContextImpl.deserialize(TreeTypeAdapter.java:162) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar!/:na]
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:1003) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar!/:na]
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:932) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar!/:na]
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11.read(TypeAdapters.java:296) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar!/:na]
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$11.read(TypeAdapters.java:306) ~[gson-2.8.6.jar!/:na]
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "facd4e72-48e4-4cc5-a524-6ae85aa7a735"
2023-Oct-12 12:30:54.253 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-7] c.s.g.p.a.PaymentFlowController - Error while performing flow steps, java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "facd4e72-48e4-4cc5-a524-6ae85aa7a735",{}

We are expecting if someone faced similar exception and what is solution or work around or there is issue reported in version that we are using.
What version has this fix implemented?